# Custom Action with wix-maven-plugin

Tags: wix

I would like to create a Windows Installer (MSI) for the installation of my java application. I plan to use WiX (http://wixtoolset.org/) with the maven plugin wix-maven-plugin (http://wix-maven.github.io/wix-maven-plugin/).

I need to run a batch script during installation and as far as I know the only way to do this is to create a custom action. Unfortunately there is a text on the website of the maven plugin which seems to say that this does not work:

`Wix custom actions are not included as a lifecycle for building in this plugin.`

Does anybody know if that means that I cannot use custom actions if I create my msi-package with wix-maven-plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can include and call upon custom actions.

The intent of

> Wix custom actions are not included as a lifecycle for building in this plugin.

Is that this maven-plugin is only intended for building of msi/msp/wixlib/bundle (lifecycles) and that for any custom action binary you will need separate build such as [nar-maven-plugin](http://maven-nar.github.io/) or [npanday-maven-plugin](https://incubator.apache.org/npanday/docs/1.5.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT/index.html).

I will try and make that clearer in the documentation.